# How can change the github user in vscode to push to my second account?

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code (Windows) and Github and it is working great. 
Now I created a new Github account and I would like to push changes to it too but VSCode uses my old github account which leads to a permission denied.

How can I configure the new account in VSCode?

Comment: You should add a remote and push to it. And you can't do it in vscode, you have to do it in command line

Comment: That is what I tried but git tries to push to my new github account with my old user. How can I tell to use the new account?

Comment: $ git push
remote: Permission to newAccount/DSTool.git denied to olduser.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/newAccount/DSTool.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now I found it. You need to remove the old account in Windows Credential Manager. After that you will be ask to enter your (new) credentials while doing a git push.